# generating multiple plots for multiple columns

Tags: python, plot

recently I watched Pydata 2019 video and I came upon Pandas tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8upGdZMlkYM&list=PLGVZCDnMOq0oywykwgVAcGvsGzagyMbwS

in 23:40 there are three plots for multiple columns but when I plot it, it plots everything in one plot

Am I missing one argument?

Comment: could you include the code you're running and the output you're getting?  making it into a ["Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps everybody

Answer (score 0):

In `matplotlib` you can use `subplots(rows, columns)` which gives you many `axes` and then you can draw on separated `axes`.

In movie you can also see word `axes` so he also created somewhere `axes` with separated plots. You would have to watch all movie to find code which he used to create axes. Or find full code from movie and test it. It also use `seaborn` and some settings which maybe automatically create plots in separated axes.

---

Simple example which draws pandas columns in separated axes.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,2,3],
    'B': [2,3,1],
    'C': [2,1,3],
})

figure, axes = plt.subplots(3,1)

df['A'].plot(ax=axes[0])
df['B'].plot(ax=axes[1])
df['C'].plot(ax=axes[2])

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** at the beginning of movie you can see link to tutorial with all code

[Tutorial: Time Series Analysis with Pandas](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-time-series-analysis-with-pandas/) and there you can see full line with

```
   .plot(..., subplots=True)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,2,3],
    'B': [2,3,1],
    'C': [2,1,3],
})

axex = df[['A','B', 'C']].plot(subplots=True)

plt.show()
```